# How can I do a verbose compile in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

In play framework 2.0.8 with Java is it possible to do a verbose compile?

Currently I only see:

> [info] Compiling 131 Scala sources and 10 Java sources to ...

I'm trying to determine why so many files are recompiled when changing a controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Play wraps sbt, so you could use the sbt command `set logLevel in compile := Level.Debug` within the play console to set the logging level. Source: [Configure and use logging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Howto/logging.html#level)

Changing a controller could trigger the routes compiler, which would need reverse routes to be recompiled, and then potentially anything using those reverse routes as well. I'm not sure of the details, but I can almost guarantee the routes compiler is involved with most mass re-compiles.

Comment: I believe the correct command is actually `logLevel in compile := Level.Debug`. The word 'set' is not required and actually causes an error in 0.13.9 sbt.

Comment: @mttdbrd You would use `set` from within the sbt console. I think you mean that you don't need it within build.sbt itself?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I didn't obviously read your answer very closely as I see the bit about the console now. Apologies.