# How to enable Play 2.3 compilation logs?

Tags: compilation, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play 2.3.2 for my application.
Even if I don't change a source file, something is always compiling when I run my tests or refresh my browser.

Exemple when an unknown file is compiling :

```
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /my-app/target/scala-2.10/test-classes
```

How can I have more logs to see what files are compiled in order to see where the problem comes from ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a verbose compile in Play Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118856/how-can-i-do-a-verbose-compile-in-play-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LimbSoup for the solution.
Here is what you need to add in the `build.sbt` file :

```
logLevel in compile := Level.Debug
```