# How to find out what happened when SBT says "javac returned nonzero exit code"?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to move our projects to Java 8. When I run a compile I get this:

```
[error] (MyProject/compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

This doesn't happen with Java 7. I suspect it's something to do with us using Lombok.

Is there any way to get the actual output from the javac? I've tried "last" and "lastgrep" but I only see SBT logs.

I'm using SBT 0.13.8

Thanks.
Ashley

Comment: You should set the output level of SBT to be more verbose, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118856/how-can-i-do-a-verbose-compile-in-play-framework

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that didn't seem to help in this case. I can see the files SBT thinks have changed but not the output of javac:

'[debug] Attempting to call com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool@7d3bdc68 directly...'
'[warn] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6'
'[error] (MyProject/compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code'
'[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 30-Jun-2015 09:06:43'

Comment: For anyone hitting the same problem as me, it was due to Lombok and the "val" feature with Java 8. Removing that allowed javac to complete ok. The question still remains, could I get SBT to give me more info rather than me finding it by trial and error?

Comment: I've seen this when upgrading from sbt 0.13.7 to 0.13.8. Unfortunately I don't know of a solution.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2256 to report this to the SBT authors.

Answer (score 1):

When `javaHome` setting is set, sbt calls `javac` by forking the process, and attempts to screen scrape the error message out of the output, which is error-prone. sbt 1.2.0-RC3 improves it a bit, but it's a hack.

One way to avoid that is to make sure `javaHome` setting is set to `None`. Around 2015 sbt-extras used to set `javaHome` quietly from `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but I think that's been dropped since 2016 in https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/pull/160. Since this question was asked in June 2015, maybe that's what it was hitting at the time. If you're using sbt-extras, please update to the latest.

This might be further supported by Parag's [answer/observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604677/3827):

> The error message disappeared on my Mac when I removed the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `.bash_profile` and then restarting Terminal.

If you continue to see this issue using sbt 1.x, please report on https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/520

Answer (score 0):

I had SBT 0.13.9, RHEL and OpenJDK1.8 installed and was getting the same error (no further stack trace), and swapping to Oracle's JDK fixed it. Probably some issue with javac-configuration, but didn't manage to quickly fix it with the OpenJDK. Probably not the best solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The error message disappeared on my Mac when I removed the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `.bash_profile` and then restarting Terminal.