# sbt gives "javac returned nonzero exit code error" without any information

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using sbt to compile a play framework application. The Scala compilation works fine but the java compilation fails without any info. How to find out what is wrong? The Scala errors are showing up but not Java errors.

I found similar questions like this one, [How to find out what happened when SBT says "javac returned nonzero exit code"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132664/how-to-find-out-what-happened-when-sbt-says-javac-returned-nonzero-exit-code), but didn't see any answer that can help find out the exact cause. Is there any flag to make sbt output the java compile errors?

This is what I get. I am using sbt 0.13.15 with Play 2.6.5, Scala 2.12.3.

```
[debug] Scala compilation took 27.800482243 s
[error] (MyProject/compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 84 s, completed Oct 24, 2017 6:01:38 PM
```

Comment: Does a `sbt clean` help? I get these errors sometimes when editing the routes file or switching branches and some old auto-generated sources are still lying around.

Comment: No...doesn't help. I always do clean. I also tried with debug logging but that didn't help as well.

Comment: Was there a previous working state, and then it broke? If so, what did you change? If not, are you able to reproduce the problem in a small, self-contained project?

Comment: A small project works fine. I just took Play starter application and it works fine. So, no issues with the environment itself. But, this project always failed. It gave me some Java code errors before. Once I fixed them, now it just fails without any details. If I take all the Java files and get the command line from the sbt debug output and compile it manually, it works fine. So, I know that there are no more errors in the code. Not sure, what is Javac failing for